# Combine netem with pfifo_fast

Tags: linux, networking, network-traffic

I am unable to combine **netem** with **pfifo_fast** so that at the root I have pfifo_fast and then netem as sub childs on the same interface.

I can afford to run
`sudo tc qdisc add dev <interface_name> root handle 1:0 pfifo_fast` and then
`sudo tc qdisc add dev <interface_name> parent 1:1 handle 10: netem rate 200mbit`
but running the same 2 commands but with swapped positions for pfifo_fast and netem I get `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported`. What is the cause of this and is it even possible to get it as I want?

Comment: Where's the rest of your config? I can't see you defining `10` anywhere, and am surprised this is working in the first incantation ...

Comment: To be honest I'm pretty new to this. There's nothing else as config. What would you need as information? EDIT: The use of `10` is what I've found in [documentation](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem#combining_netem_with_other_qdiscs)